# Cypress - log response data from an request after a click()

Tags: testing, cypress, e2e-testing

Although I know this may not be considered as a best practice, but what I want to achieve is to silently delete a record from a database after the same was created throughout UI. In htat way I want to keep our test environment clear as much as possible and reduce the noise of test data.

After my tests create a new record by clicking over the UI, I wait for POST request to finish and then I would like to extract the id from the response (so I can reuse it to silently delete that record by calling the `cy.request('DELETE', '/id')`).

Here's a sample test I have put on as a showcase. I'm wondering why nothing is logged in this example.

```
it('GET cypress and log', () => {
  cy.server()
    .route('**/repos/cypress-io/cypress*')
    .as('getSiteInfo');

  cy.visit('https://www.cypress.io/dashboard');

  cy.get('img[alt="Cypress.io"]')
    .click()
    .wait('@getSiteInfo')
    .then((response) => {
      cy.log(response.body)
    })
})
```

As far as I can see from here https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait.html#Alias this should be fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

your code contains two problems.

**First**:
The `click` triggers a new page to be loaded but cypress does not wait until the `PageLoad` event is raised (because you do not use `visit`). On my PC the Request takes about 5 seconds until it is triggered after the `click`. So you should use `wait(..., { timeout: 10000 })`.

**Second:**
`wait()` yields the XHR object, not the response. So your code within `then` is not correct. Also the body is passed as object. So you should use `JSON.stringify()` to see the result in the command log.

This code works:

```
describe("asda", () => {
    it('GET cypress and log', () => {
        cy.server()
          .route('**/repos/cypress-io/cypress*')
          .as('getSiteInfo');

        cy.visit('https://www.cypress.io/dashboard');

        cy  
          .get('img[alt="Cypress.io"]')
          .click()
          .wait('@getSiteInfo', { timeout: 20000 })
          .then((xhr) => {
            cy.log(JSON.stringify(xhr.response.body))
          })
      })
})
```

Comment: Thanks Josef! Regarding the timeout stuff. For me it works without the optional timeout being set, I guess it was just a temporary glitch. The JSON.stringify definitely logs a data I wanted to log and thanks for that.

However, unfortunately, this does not resolve a problem on the project I am working on. It logs just an empty object {} and what I believe it causes is because we use "fetch" network requests rather than XHR's.

Comment: @Alen Cypress is not able to intercept `fetch` requests right now. As far as I know they are working on a network layer rewrite to enable this. I am not sure if this can also be solved by using the chrome debugger interface? Also you should search in the github issues. maybe another one already has found a workaround for intercepting fetch requests. I have no link I can share with you because we do not use `fetch` requests and thus I have no experience with it.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of route and server method, try intercept directly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Any code samples you'd like to add to this? Answer is very lacking.