# How to Measure XHR Response Duration in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress, ui-automation

When I click on a button, an XHR (POST) is triggered, How can i measure the response time for that request?

```
cy.log(JSON.stringify(xhr.response.duration))
```

The above is empty

```
cy.log(JSON.stringify(xhr.response.body))
```

But the body is not empty.

Comment: May be this can help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59324075/cypress-log-response-data-from-an-request-after-a-click

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66354560/cypress-xhr-duration-no-longer-captured-with-cy-intercept