# CYPRESS - XHR duration no longer captured with cy.intercept()

Tags: cypress

Cypress are about to deprecate **cy.route()** and **cy.server()** in use of **cy.intercept()**

Here is my OLD Code, that would capture XHR time and output

```
        cy.server()
        cy.route('POST', api_URL_Live).as('CONS');

        cy.wait('@CONS').then((xhr) => {
            CONSTime = Number(JSON.stringify(xhr.duration));
        });
```

This worked perfectly and would out put the duration to a file

New code that no longer captures duration

```
        cy.intercept('POST', api_URL_Live).as('CONS');

        cy.wait('@CONS').then((xhr) => {
            CONSTime = Number(JSON.stringify(xhr.duration));
        });
```

Does anyone know why this functionality no longer works, any help appreciated?

Comment: If you log the CONSTime what value do you get. Also do you get any errors ?

Comment: @AlapanDas Just "undefined" as a value, no errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The APIs of [`cy.intercept`](https://on.cypress.io/intercept) and [`cy.route`](https://on.cypress.io) have some overlap, but are not the same.

`duration` is an undocumented property of `cy.route`, but it does work, although it is not formally supported.

Because it was undocumented and rarely used in `cy.route`, it was not considered for implementation in `cy.intercept`.

You can still measure a request's duration using `cy.route` - `cy.route` is not going to be deleted, leaving your code broken. It will most likely be moved to a plugin once `cy.intercept` is stable enough for most common use cases.

If you would like to do the same with `cy.intercept`, you can measure by using callbacks:

```js
cy.intercept('POST', url, (req) => {
  const startTime = Date.now()
  req.reply(res => {
    // measure the time between request received and response received
    totalTime = Date.now() - startTime
  })
})
```

There is an open feature request to add timing data to `cy.intercept`: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/15969